# append data to a pipe-delimited file

Tags: batch-file, powershell, pipe, delimiter

I have a pipe-delimited file containing 5 columns. I need to append a sixth (pipe-delimited) column to the end of each row.

Old data:

```
a|b|c|d|e
p|q|r|s|t
```

New Data:

```
a|b|c|d|e|x
p|q|r|s|t|x
```

The sixth column (x) is a value which read from a text-file.

I am wondering if there is a quick way to append this data into existing data-file using powershell? The file contains variable number of rows (between 10  to 100,000)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple text operations should work:

```
$replace = 'x'

(Get-Content file.txt) -replace '$',"|$replace"

a|b|c|d|e|x
p|q|r|s|t|x
```

For large files, you can do this:

```
$replace = 'x'
filter add-data {$_ -replace '$',"|$replace"}
Get-Content file.txt -ReadCount 1000  | add-data | add-content newfile.txt
```

That should produce very good performance with large files.

Comment: in my existing code, I am doing some operations with get-content on that file. So, I used your answer and it is working great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data does not have any headers in the CSV already, then you'll have to define the headers with the `-Headers` parameter of the `Import-Csv` cmdlet. To run the example below, put your data into a file called `c:\test\test.csv`. Then, run the script in PowerShell or PowerShell ISE.

```
# 1. Import the data
$Data = Import-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Path c:\test\test.csv -Header prop1,prop2,prop3,prop4,prop5;

# 2. Add a new member to each row
foreach ($Item in $Data) {
    Add-Member -InputObject $Item -MemberType NoteProperty -Name prop6 -Value x;
}

# 3. Export the data to a new CSV file
$Data | Export-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Path c:\test\test.new.csv -NoTypeInformation;

# 4. Remove the double quotes around values
(Get-Content -Path c:\test\test.new.csv -Raw) -replace '"','' | Set-Content -Path c:\test\test.new.csv;
```

### Original Data

The source data in `c:\test\test.csv` should look like this (according to your original post):

```
a|b|c|d|e
p|q|r|s|t
```

### Resulting Data

After executing the script, your resulting data in `c:\test\test.new.csv` will look like this:

```
prop1|prop2|prop3|prop4|prop5|prop6
a|b|c|d|e|x
p|q|r|s|t|x
```

### Random Sample Data Generation

Here is a short script that will generate a 10,000-line, randomized sample file to `c:\test\test.csv`:

```
$Random = { [System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::ASCII.GetString((1..5 | % { [byte](Get-Random -Minimum 97 -Maximum 122); })).ToCharArray(); };
1..10000 | % { @('{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}|{4}' -f (& $Random)) } | Set-Content -Path c:\test\test.csv;
```

After running my first script against this sample data (**10,000** lines), the result took: **1,729** milliseconds to execute. I would say that's pretty fast. Not that this is a race or anything.

I ran the sample file generator again, to generate **100,000** lines of data. After running the same script against that data, it took **19,784** milliseconds to run. It's roughly proportional to the 10,000 line test, but all in all, still doesn't take all that long. Is this a one-time thing, or does it need to be run on a schedule?

Comment: excellent, let me try that @TrevorSullivan. I just hope it does not take a long time to process.

Comment: It should be very fast. I can try to replicate it with a few thousand lines.

Comment: I've updated the code sample with a script to generate some random data for you. You can adjust the number of iterations by modifying the `1..10000` bit to a larger number.

Comment: in my existing code, I am doing some operations with get-content on that file. So, I used the answer by @mjolinor and it is working great. Thanks for your answer too, its an alternative that I have learned. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the file line for line and just append the value in the loop:

Edit full sample code:

```
function append{
process{
foreach-object {$_ + "|x"}}}
$a = get-content yourcsv.csv
$a | append | set-content yourcsv.csv
```

Comment: is this suitable for files with 100,000+ data rows?

Comment: it should be fast enough, give me a second to update the post